# fetch data from two tables and ignore the repeated values in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables in laravel. table_2 have a foreign key i-e users_id so I want to fetch data from both tables and remove the duplicate entries. for that purpose I create two queries in my controller

```
$new=DB::table('tabl-1')
              ->join('tbl2','tbl1.id','=','tbl2.foreign_key') 
              ->orWhereDate('created_at','<' ,Carbon::today())
              ->orWhereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
              ->orWhereNull('created_at')
              ->select('tbl_1.created_at as date','tbl1.foreign_key as data_id')
              ->where('user_id',$users_id)
              ->get()
              ->toArray();

$old = DB::table('tbl-2')
              ->join('tbl1','tbl2.foreign_key','=','tbl1.id') 
              ->where('user_id',$users_id)
              ->whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM tbl2 GROUP BY foreign_key)')
              ->select('tbl_2.created_at as date','tbl2.foreign_key as data_id')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
$data=array_merge($old,$new);
```

old array working fine but new array printing duplicate value of data.id , what should I do so I can get all data from old array but when moves in to new array it shows all rows except already show in old array

Comment: there is a `array_unique()`function, did you try it?

Comment: Maybe this can be help you https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique once data merged